# What's the meaning of Antd <Form.List> "fieldKey" property?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Under the Dynamic Form nest Items [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/2yff4).
There is a line

> Nest dynamic field need extends field. Pass field.name and field.fieldKey to nest item.

But even if i removed the fieldKey and {...field} property, the example still works well, so why should i set fieldKey？

Answer (score 0):

From my experience only name prop is obligatory and it sets the key of nested objects.

Comment: i feel the same as you. Field: { fieldKey: 0, isListField: true, key: 0,name: 0} . The Field property values are same as index. Don't know why not just give the index as parameter.

Comment: It seems like fieldKey would work as key prop in React, so fieldKey is used by antd library to know which field it is if the quantity or order of form items was changed.